# Javascript onclick button change

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
   <img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/yes.png" onclick="save(this);" id="btnyes" value="Yes"> &nbsp; 
     <img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/no.png" id="btnno" onclick="save(this);" value="No">
       <img id="yes" style="display:none" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png"  alt="">
        <img id="no" style="display:none" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png"  alt="">
```

when i click on yes button it should change to green tick and
when i click on no button it should change to red tick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function save(obj) {

  if(obj.value='yes'){
    document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none';
  } 
  else if {
    document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'block';
  }
}

</script>
```

The script for this function is above.but when i click on any of thesetwo buttons no change happens..What is the error?

Comment: `obj.value=='yes'` not `obj.value='yes'`

Comment: no change still same pb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your file:

This is your html:

```
 <img onclick="save(this);" id="btnyes" value="Yes">
```

This is your JS:

```
if(obj.value='yes'){
document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none';
}
```

"yes" **does not** equal "Yes". Also, `if(obj.value='yes')` is not checking for the value of `obj.value`.

This snippet below is wrong. You either need to specify `else if("condition")` or change it to `else` .

```
else if{
document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: what should i do to change in all rows?

Comment: Have you modified your code? If so, what does it look like now? Also, what do you mean by rows ? What exactly are you seeing when you click on one of the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Only input elements have value attribute. But you are using value inside the image so you can use:

```
if(obj.getAttribute('value')=='yes'){//compare with == not with =
```

---

Recommendation:

Do use html5 data-* attribute. For eg. `data-value="yes"` and then use `getAttribute('data-value')`.

---

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ubcq7pom/)

Comment: You may need `if(obj.getAttribute('data-value').toLowerCase()=='yes'){`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98304/discussion-between-user-and-bhojendra-nepal).

Comment: in demo? its alerting 'yes'

Answer (score 0):

First, there is a syntax error in your javascript code near the else if condition.

Second, you cannot use "value" attribute for images.

Third, you are comparing using a "=" whereas it shall be "=="

Last, you are comparing 'yes' with 'Yes'. So that being case sensitive, the comparison fails.

I have made generic changes to your  code. Please try that and see if you get right alerts. And then you can add your code in it as you wish.

```
<script language="javascript">

function save(obj){


if(obj.getAttribute("value") =='Yes'){
 alert("I am in Yes");

 } 
 else {

   alert("I am in No");

     }
}

</script>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of things to correct.

First, its `obj.value == 'yes'` not `obj.value='yes'`

Second, you should use `obj.getAttribute('value')` instead of `obj.value`.

Third, in your code, you are using `<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png` two times. But it seems like you should use `<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/red.png` on the second time.

The whole code looks like;

**HTML**

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/yes.png" onclick="save(this);" id="btnyes" value="yes"/> &nbsp; 
<img src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/no.png" onclick="save(this);" id="btnno" value="no"/> 
<img id="yes" style="display:none" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/green.png"  alt="">
<img id="no" style="display:none" src="<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/red.png"  alt="">
```

**JavaScript**

```
function save(obj){
  if(obj.getAttribute('value')=='yes'){
    document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'block';
  } else{
    document.getElementById('btnyes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('btnno').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('yes').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('no').style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

Here is a working demo https://jsfiddle.net/sa215dv0/1/

Hope this helps